# Not all JSON array elements are created using jq command in Bash

Tags: jq, azure-cli

Inside of a while loop I'm trying to build json objects and add them to an array then write this array to a json file using jq commands. Each json object in the array gets one of its  properties from a file as shown below:

```
input="names.csv" 
while IFS= read -r secretName || [ -n "$secretName" ]; 
do      
    value=""
    value=$(echo "$secretValue" | tr -d '\n' | tr -d '\r' )
    value="{\"name\":\"$secretName\",\"newValue\":\"****\"}"  #get $secretname from names.txt 
    
    echo '[]' | jq ". += [$value]" > jsonOutput.json
    
done < $input
```

The expected output should be a JSON array of objects with multiple objects in it but I'm only seeing the last object. Since the input file has three names in it, the output should also have three objects in the array. I would also like to give the array a key and the output should look something like the following:

```
{"secrets":[
  {
    "name": "name1",
    "newValue": "****"
  },
  {
    "name": "name2",
    "newValue": "****"
  },
  {
    "name": "name3",
    "newValue": "****"
  }
]
}
```

I am very new to jq and the examples in various posts that I have seen left more questions than they answer. Please let me know why the first two objects are missing in the array and how I can assign a key to the array object.

Comment: Your attempt fails because with each iteration `echo '[]' | jq …` will start out with a new document. You never read what you have written in previous iterations. But as `while IFS= read -r secretName || [ -n "$secretName" ]; do …` from your approach simply reads the input file line by line, assigning each line in its entirety to `secretName` (in contrast to what the input file's extension would suggest), the whole task could be reduced to one jq call: `input="names.csv"; jq -Rn '{secrets: [{name: inputs, newValue: "****"}]}' "$input" > jsonOutput.json`.

Comment: What do the options -Rn do? I've searched all over but I haven't seen an explanation for how they work together.

Comment: Have a look at `jq --help`, or `man jq`, or the [online manual](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#invoking-jq). `-R` reads each input line as a string, and `-n` makes jq start with a single input value instance, so with no forks on top level there will also be only one output instance (your top-level object).

Comment: Your solution  works great but it took me a while to figure out how to read from the resulting json file.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop looks unnecessarily complex (and maybe you don't even need it at all). Here's how you would construct a JSON array with computed values with jq in a shell loop:

```
input="names.csv"
while IFS= read -r secretName || [ -n "$secretName" ];
do
    jq --arg name "$secretName" -n '{$name, newValue: "****"}'
done < "$input" | jq -s '{secrets:.}' > jsonOutput.json
```

This will create a stream of JSON objects first and will then collect them into a single array with the `-s` (`--slurp`) option.

It's also imperative, that you quote all your shell variables when expanding!

---

But you don't need to read the file with the shell at all, jq can already read text files just fine:

```
jq -R '{name: ., newValue: "****"}' "$input" | jq -s "{secrets:.}"
```

Alternatively, with a single jq process:

```
jq -Rn '[{name: inputs, newValue: "****"}]|{secrets:.}' "$input"
```